# Dividing elements of array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Hello I'm a beginner programmer and I know there must be a simple way to do this but for some reason can't find the answer. I have two arrays and just want to divide each element by the elements in the other array. for example

```
a= np.array([2,4,6,8,10,12])
b=np.array([2,1,2,1,2,1])
so that the result is (1,4,3,8,5,12)....
```

I tried doing this over a for loop :

```
for i in range(a):
    c = a[i]/b[i]
```

but it doesnt work and gives the error 
"TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index"

Comment: Try `a / b` without the `for` loop, `numpy` does sensible things with mathematical operations on the whole array.

Comment: `a/b` will work as others have pointed out. The other problem is that you have `range(a)` where you should use `range(len(a))`.

Comment: @VBB yes I found out that that was my real problem, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just divide the arrays themselves (`a/b`)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([2,4,6,8,10,12])

In [3]: b = np.array([2,1,2,1,2,1])

In [4]: a/b
Out[4]: array([ 1,  4,  3,  8,  5, 12])
```

This happens because numpy overloads the `__div__` method of the `ndarray` to divide the elements of the arrays and output the resulting array (the implementation is mostly in C code so it'd be difficult to link you to exactly where this happens)

Comment: Just please, don't forget to clarify the direct division is possible due to the nature of Numpy operator overloading.